# IOS trueHeading different values when opening

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, location, compass

I create an AR app using GPS tracking and compass with Unity3D.

For example, when I open app, the trueHeading is 260, and when I close it and open again with different orientation, then turn the device to previous state, the trueHeading is 210.

I try IOS native app with swift, but same problem occurs.

Here is my Swift code

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController ,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var lm:CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lm = CLLocationManager()
        lm.delegate = self

        lm.startUpdatingHeading()

        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(printHeading), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    @objc func printHeading() {
        print(self.lm.heading?.trueHeading)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

The same problem occurs with `magneticHeading`.

The [IOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clheading/1423568-trueheading) says that **The value in this property represents the heading relative to the geographic North Pole**. But it don't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you can't get identical/similar true/magnetic heading
from your app's run to next run - poor repeatability.

As a  first step, check if built-in compass app gives the identical result as your app. If both results agree, that is your hardware's performance. What you can do is almost nothing.

I tested my app with two different iPhones. Even if I put both phones to the same direction quite often, both give non-trivial differences - 10-20 deg. By comparing with true (SUNTO's) compass I realized one phone has poorer performance (real value and repeatability) for some reason. I want to manually calibrate iphone's compass but no such UI/API is given w/ iOS - only ios determines when to calibrate.

True heading is given just by adding offset to magnetic heading, whose offset is determined by the location. So if magnetic heading gives poor repeatability, so does true heading.